# Enforcing one async observable at a time

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I'm trying to integrate some TPL async into a larger Rx chain using `Observable.FromAsync`, like in this small example:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace rxtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            await Observable.Generate(new Random(), x => true,
                                      x => x, x => x.Next(250, 500))
                .SelectMany((x, idx) => Observable.FromAsync(async ct =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("start:  " + idx.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(x, ct);
                    Console.WriteLine("finish: " + idx.ToString());
                    return idx;
                }))
                .Take(10)
                .LastOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I've noticed that this seems to start all the async tasks concurrently rather than doing them one at a time, which causes memory usage of the app to balloon. The `SelectMany` appears to be acting no different than a `Merge`.

Here, I see output like this:

```
start:  0
start:  1
start:  2
...
```

I'd like to see:

```
start:  0
finish: 0
start:  1
finish: 1
start:  2
finish: 2
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want to write serial code with a parallel library?

Comment: @AustinSalonen These tools are designed to work with asynchronous code, not just parallel code.  Not all asynchronous code need be parallelized.  He is using entirely appropriate tools here.

Comment: @Servy:  I was really just poking to see what was really going on here.  You could simply block in the `FromAsync` call to satisfy this scenario.  It may not be _correct_ but it looks like that's what he wants.

Comment: @AustinSalonen That would not be maintaining asynchrony, and would be an inappropriate use of these tools.  Given that the OP is using these tools, clearly they wish to find an asynchronous solution to this problem.  Finding an entirely synchronous solution to this problem is pretty trivial.

Comment: @AustinSalonen If you think a question isn't clear enough, asking for clarification will be more productive than leaving a snarky comment assuming the person doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: Asking for clarification was literally what I did.  It appeared you wanted serial execution of tasks, which opens up other solutions.  It wasn't snarky at all.  People over-engineer solutions on this site all the time; I'm guilty of it as much as anyone and asking the simple, obvious questions fishes that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the `SelectMany` to a `Select` with a `Concat`:

```
    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        await Observable.Generate(new Random(), x => true,
                                  x => x, x => x.Next(250, 500))
            .Take(10)
            .Select((x, idx) => Observable.FromAsync(async ct =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start:  " + idx.ToString());
                await Task.Delay(x, ct);
                Console.WriteLine("finish: " + idx.ToString());
                return idx;
            }))
            .Concat()
            .LastOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

EDIT - I moved the Take(10) up the chain because the Generate won't block - so it stops this running away.

The `Select` projects each event into a stream representing an async task that will start on Subscription. `Concat` accepts a stream of streams and subscribes to each successive sub-stream when the previous has completed, concatenating all the streams into a single flat stream.

Comment: Edited to add explanation, plus a small optimzation to prevent the Generate running wild.

Comment: Alternatively, `.Take(1).Repeat()`.

Comment: Actually that would be `.Take(1).Repeat().Take(10)`, which is kind of silly.

Comment: Nailed it - if you want some degree of parallelism, use `Merge(anInt)` instead of the Concat here

Comment: If the order of execution matters, use `.Select().Concat()`. If you want to execute operations as soon as possible and don't care about the order, use `.SelectMany()`.