# Enforcing one Async Observable at a time in F#

Tags: f#, async-await, system.reactive

I have an observable sequence of things that need to be mapped to
a C# task. These C# tasks should not run concurrently, but one after
another. Basically, I need to achieve the F# equivalent of this C#
question:

> [Enforcing one async observable at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20404572/2219418)

Naively translating this C# code gives something like the following:

```
let run (idx:int) (delay:int) =
    async {
        sprintf "start: %i (%i)" idx delay |> System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine
        let! t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(delay) |> Async.AwaitTask
        sprintf "finish: %i" idx  |> System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine
        t
    }

    Observable.generate (new Random()) (fun _ -> true) id (fun s -> s.Next(250, 500))
    |> Observable.take 20
    |> Observable.mapi(fun idx delay -> idx, delay)
    |> Observable.bind(fun (idx, delay) -> Observable.ofAsync (run idx delay))
    |> Observable.subscribe ignore
    |> ignore
```

Which does not work as expected because I don't wait for a result anywhere. Is there even
a way to do this in F# without blocking a thread, just like C#'s await would?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43584824/9723177

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a handy library that exists in F# called AsyncSeq:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/

It's very similar to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` that was added to C# 8.0, this gives you a nice solution to what you are after.

Solution:

```
open System
open FSharp.Control
open FSharp.Control.Reactive

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    let run (idx:int) (delay:int) =
        async {
            sprintf "start: %i (%i)" idx delay |> Console.WriteLine
            do! Async.Sleep delay
            sprintf "finish: %i" idx  |> Console.WriteLine
        }

    Observable.generate (new Random()) (fun _ -> true) id (fun s -> s.Next(250, 500))
    |> Observable.take 20
    |> Observable.mapi(fun idx delay -> idx, delay)
    |> AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered
    |> AsyncSeq.iterAsync (fun (idx,delay) -> run idx delay)
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

    0
```

`AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered` does the work of subscribing to your `Observable` and acts as `AsyncSeq` source which you can pipeline on top of. Finally we call `Async.RunSynchronously` to kick it off and wait on the entrypoint thread.

Note: I also update `run` as it was returning `Async<Async<unit>>` and I assume that wasn't intended.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. And indeed, run returning Async<Async> was not intentional.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. But Tom, it's been 18 months! What happened!